# Can't Assign to Function Call (Python)

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```
class Quadratic:

    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c

    def function(self, x):
        self.F(x) = a*(x**2) + b*x + c
        return F(x)

    def table(self, lower, upper, varz):
        inc = np.absolute(upper-lower) / varz
        print inc
        for i in range(0 , varz - 1):
            self.F(lower)
            lower = lower + inc
        #lower bound,upper bound, number of values

    def roots():
        x1 = (-b + math.sqrt(b**2 - 4*a*c)) / (2*a)
        x2 = (-b - math.sqrt(b**2 - 4*a*c)) / (2*a)
        return x1, x2

    def dump(self):
        print self.n
```

Whenever I try and run this script, I get the following:

```
line 15
self.F(x) = a*(x**2) + b*x + c
SyntaxError: can't assign to function call
```

Any help or ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What's to explain? You can't assign to a function call. If you're trying to ***define*** a function, use `def` or `lambda`.

Comment: What is `F`? It's not clear what you're trying to do.

Comment: what is `self.F(x)`?

Comment: I think it's a result of confusion about variable names, `self`, and functions.

Answer (score 2):

It is not clear (to me at least) what it is you're trying to achieve, but perhaps it is as simple as this:

```
def F(self, x):
    return self.a * (x ** 2) + self.b * x + c
```

Answer (score 1):

As you might have guessed, `F(x)` is a function call. You're calling the function `F`, which does not actually exist, passing it the argument `x`, which does not actually exist either. You need to give your variables legal names, like `f_of_x`.

Answer (score 1):

try with:

```
def __init__(self, a,b,c):
    self.a = a
    self.b = b
    self.c = c
    self.F = lambda x: a*(x**2)+b*x+c
```

and discard the function() method